# How to attach jar file source in JetBrains MPS while debugging a java code?

Tags: jar, mps

I am trying to debug my java class in Jetbrains MPS, but it is calling one jar file, hence i am not able to see the code implementation.
I am having the source jar file for it, if anyone can help me with how to attach the same so that i can debug the jar file code would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can you Another Java IDE, or in your module property you can configure to attach source file which you can see during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to use IntelliJ IDEA (or other IDEs) and configure t to see the generated sources, the jar file as well as the sources jar and initiate remote debugging of the MPS process.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to to the same... it will be a great help i am struggling with this...
I am having IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse and netbeans so if you can guide me or give me link where i can see the steps will be a great help...